# Python return a result if numbers in one list are the same in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a lotto simulator where the code generates 6 random unique numbers out of 45 for both the winning numbers and 1000 players, both of which are stored as lists.

What I would like to do is calculate the number of winners per division.

So 1st division if all 6 winning numbers equal to the 6 numbers the player has, 2nd division if any 5 of the 6 winning numbers equal to the 5 of the 6 numbers the player has, 3rd division if any 4 of the 6 winning numbers equal to the 4 of the 6 numbers the player has, so on.

Currently my code only looks for 1st division and does not count how many times a match (if any) of 6/6 is found. This is where I get stuck how do I do this while also needing to find matches of 5/6, 4/6, 3/6.

I am using a binary search algorithm to compare the winning numbers against the numbers the player has.

```
winNum = [37, 10, 36, 26, 19, 43]
lotto = [[5, 19, 21, 24, 30, 38], [10, 11, 15, 24, 32, 34], ...]

# Calculates the total number of winners for each division.    
def totalWinners():
    target = winNum
    search = binarySearch
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(lotto)):
        found = search(target, lotto, 0, len(lotto)-1)
        if found == -1:
            print(lotto[i])
            print("search unsuccessful...")

#Binary search algorithm.
def binarySearch (target, p, left, right):
     l = left
     r = right
     while l <= r:
         f = (l+r)//2
         if target == p[f]:
             return f          
         elif target < p[f]:
             r = f - 1         
         else:
             l = f + 1         
     return -1
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better job for [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). You get easier and efficient calculation of intersections for free.

```
winNumSet = set(winNum)
for entry in lotto:
    division = len(set(entry) & winNumSet)
```

That tells you what "division" that entry is in. Deal with it in whatever manner is most appropriate for your overall goal.

Obviously if you have control over how `winNum` and the elements of `lotto` are generated, it would be more efficient to start with sets in the first place.